# Run a background thread in apache deployed flask script

Tags: python, multithreading, apache, ubuntu, flask

I have a flask script which runs a background loop constantly and at a given time runs a process. When I ran this on my local machine for testing purposes it ran fine and the background thread worked, however, once I deployed it on ubuntu using apache the background process seems to not be running

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, DateField
from wtforms.validators import Optional
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from threading import Thread
from MetocSC import scraper
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import time
import os
import re

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'key'

Bootstrap(app)

if not os.path.exists('Database.csv'):
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Type', 'Origin', 'Issue date', 'Subject', 'Date', 'Points', 'Upload date'])
    df.to_csv('Database.csv', index=False)


class SearchForm(FlaskForm):
    criteria = StringField('search')
    date = DateField('Date', validators=(Optional(),))
    submit = SubmitField('Search', render_kw={'class': 'btn btn-success'})


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    # Display data with a search bar and date search
    form = SearchForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for('results', x=form.criteria.data, y=form.date.data))
    return render_template('home.html', form=form)


@app.route('/results', defaults={'x': None, 'y': None})
@app.route('/results/<x>', defaults={'y': None})
@app.route('/results/<x>/<y>')
def results(x, y):
    if x:
        if re.search("""^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}""", x):
            date = x
            if y:
                criteria = y
            else:
                criteria = ''
    if y:
        if re.search("""^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}""", y):
            date = y
            if x:
                criteria = x
            else:
                criteria = ''

    elif not x and not y:
        date = ''
        criteria = ''

    print('date: ', date),
    print('criteria', criteria)

    df = pd.read_csv('Database.csv', index_col=[0])
    if criteria != '' and date == '':
        df = df[df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains(criteria, case=False).any(), axis=1)]
        df.drop('Upload date', inplace=True, axis=1)
        return render_template('results.html', tables=[df.to_html()], titles=[''])
    elif date != '' and criteria == '':
        df = df.loc[df['Upload date'] == date]
        df.drop('Upload date', inplace=True, axis=1)
        return render_template('results.html', tables=[df.to_html()], titles=[''])
    elif date != '' and criteria != '':
        df = df[(df['Upload date'] == date)]
        df = df[df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains(criteria, case=False).any(), axis=1)]
        df.drop('Upload date', inplace=True, axis=1)
        return render_template('results.html', tables=[df.to_html()], titles=[''])
    else:
        return 'Error: Either a date or search criteria must be provided'


@app.route('/logs')
def logs():
    df = pd.read_csv('Database.csv', index_col=[0])
    df.drop('Upload date', inplace=True, axis=1)
    return render_template('logs.html', tables=[df.to_html()], titles=[''])


def threaded_scraper():
    while True:  # Permanently run this loop as a thread
        gmt = time.gmtime(time.time())  # Get the current GMT time

        if gmt.tm_hour == 6 and gmt.tm_min == 30:  # If half 6 scrape for the day

            # region Check that it hasn't already been scraped today
            f = open('check.txt', 'r')

            if int(f.read()) == gmt.tm_mday:
                time.sleep(1)
                f.close()
            # endregion

            # region If not already scraped today then scrape
            else:
                ABPW10_data = scraper()

                df = pd.read_csv('Database.csv', index_col=[0])

                new_row = pd.DataFrame(data=
                                       {
                                           'Type': ABPW10_data['Type'],
                                           'Origin': ABPW10_data['Origin'],
                                           'Issue date': ABPW10_data['Issue date'],
                                           'Subject': ABPW10_data['Subject'],
                                           'Date': ABPW10_data['Date'],
                                           'Points': str(ABPW10_data['Points']),
                                           'Upload date': date.today()
                                       },
                    index=[0]
                                       )

                df = pd.concat([df, new_row], ignore_index=True)

                df.to_csv('Database.csv', index=False)
                # endregion

                # region Update text file to show that scraping has been done today
                with open('check.txt', 'w') as f:
                    f.write(str(gmt.tm_mday))
                    f.close()
                # endregion


        else:
            time.sleep(1)


thread = Thread(target=threaded_scraper)
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I am aware there are other potentially better ways to thread tasks in flask, however this method worked for me so I stuck with it.

I followed this tutorial to get it set up on apache https://python.plainenglish.io/how-to-securely-deploy-flask-with-apache-in-a-linux-server-environment-7eacd4c69a73

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: When you create a thread in your Python code, you do not even check for errors or capture exceptions. Start by debugging that part of your code and then update your question. Also, create minimum code examples: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have the same proble but I can't find a solution. Did you solve?

Comment: I ended up creating a separate script with the process in it and running it using crontab